# Spring boot rest controller error message always null

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

When a rest controller is called which ends up in a error being thrown, [Spring boot returns an JSON error object](https://devland.at/a/json-api-error-response-with-spring-boot). However my issue is that the `message` field is always null, even when I supply a msg to the exception. The error response JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-12-23T21:44:30.077+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/v1/example"
}
```

In my code I am throwing an exception such as this:

```
throw new RuntimeException("HELLO!");
```

But the string msg parameter never appears in the response.

I understand that I can write my own error handlers, and I am doing that. However in the event that an error occurs which I have not prepared for or handled I would like to have the error message appear in the response, what's the point in the `message` field in the Spring boot error json if not for that?

Comment: look up `@ControllerAdvice`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. Debug and make sure your `RuntimeException` is triggering. If it triggering, it will definitely throw the error message mentioned in the `RuntimeException` parameter.

My guess is your code gets an error **before the line of RuntimeException**, so it not throwing your error message.

***Use this way to throw the error message***:

Add the below code somewhere in the **service class**

```
throw new RuntimeException("Hello");
```

**In controller class** catch the exception and throw the exception

```
catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Hello!");
        }
```

**Sample complete API**:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test-api")
public ResponseEntity<?> sampleMethod(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
    try {
        // Sample code
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(e.getMessage());
    }
}:
```

Answer (score 1):

Try throwing a ResponseStatusException instead.

```
throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "HELLO!");
```